# How to clear the Invalid CGContext error in ios 7.

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I am doing one application.In that i got the error like below in ios 7.

```
       <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error.         This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

      CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

     <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

      <Error>: CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

But i didn't get that erro in previous ios 7 versions.So please guide me how to avoid these errors.And in which situation i am getting this errors.

Comment: this is a known issue in iOS 7 ( false alarm ). Appears in `UITextField`, `UITextView`, `UIWebView`, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0 Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509324/error-cgcontextsavegstate-invalid-context-0x0-error)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508048/cgcontext-invalid-context-0x0

Comment: I didn't use any appearence for controls.I am using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext for UIImageView.