# CGContext Erase Error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, runtime-error

I keep getting this error:

`Jan 31 13:56:51 Michaels-MacBook-Air.local CocoaDrawing[2129] <Error>: The function 'CGContextErase' is obsolete and will be removed in an upcoming update. Unfortunately, this application, or a library it uses, is using this obsolete function, and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system performance.`

My program doesn't call that method directly, and frustratingly, I can't find any documentation on this function.

This happens even with a blank (Cocoa) Xcode project. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Just add a Symbolic Breakpoint in Xcode and figure out where it is called from.

Comment: On iOS7 probably an error produced by iOS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628471/how-to-clear-the-invalid-cgcontext-error-in-ios-7

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. It was caused by an outdated Wacom Tablet driver. If you have such a driver installed I'd recommend removing it, then reinstalling a more recent driver. That did the trick for me.

Comment: Brilliant.  Great deduction.  I had the same issue and it was resolved when I did a clean install of the OS. I never reinstalled the Wacom driver.